# CMD command to download a file

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I'm looking for a cmd **only** command that will allow me to download a file.

No bitsadmin, no powershell, no .vbs scripts.

My own research has lead me nowhere, there only seems to be things about bitsadmin, powershell, .vbs, downloading a curl program etc

Comment: Newer Windows 10 versions has curl binary pre-installed. Another program is [aria2](https://aria2.github.io/) (cross platform).

Comment: "Download a file" term is too general. Specify a protocol.. at least... And why so restrictions - no scripts?

Comment: Akina, I want to download a .zip file, or at least an .exe

Comment: Why are there such restrictions? Are you on an ancient pre-Vista OS? If yes then you shouldn't even connect the PC to the internet

Comment: Even older windows versions do inculde `C:\Windows\System32\ftp.exe`

Answer (score 1):

wget is popular tool for Linux users to download a file from URL. There is a windows version of wget is available which can be used for the same. Here is the download link:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm